# TYPO3 DCE use curly bracket inside fluid template file

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-9.x, tx-dce

I have a DCE content element and now I need to add a json object inside this template with the text from the variables.

I tried many ways like

```
<f:format.raw>{</f:format.raw>
```

or

```
<f:format.alias map="{l: '{}', r: '}'}"> { json } </f:format.alias>
```

but nothing works.

```
<dce:format.WrapWithCurlyBraces>json</dce:format.WrapWithCurlyBraces>
```

was my last test but this generates an empty output. Is there any way to output some json with the variables from the dce inside?

```
<f:format.json>{"context": "https://schema.org/"}</f:format.json>
```

also tested, generates also an empty output.

DCE Version: 2.6.0
TYPO3: 9.5

Answer (score 1):

`<f:format.raw>{</f:format.raw>` should work. If not, you can also try `<f:format.raw value="{" />`. For example:

```
<f:format.raw value="{" />json<f:format.raw value="}" />
```

Comment: that don't work too, my test line: ````<script type="application/ld+json">
<![CDATA[{"@context" : "https://schema.org/"}]]>
</script>```` the output is only: ````<script type="application/ld+json">

</script>```` with: ````<![CDATA[{]]>"@context" : "https://schema.org/"<![CDATA[{]]>````
the output is: ````<script type="application/ld+json">
"@context" : "https://schema.org/"
</script>````

Comment: You're right. That doesn't work since TYPO3 8. I've updated my answer with a solution that should work with newer TYPO3 versions.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need that many workarounds ;) You just used the JSON-ViewHelper incorrectly. It expects a (Fluid)-array as input.

```
<f:format.json value="{context: 'https://schema.org/'}" />
```

Since the `"` in the JSON will get escaped before being output to HTML we just use `f:format:raw` on the whole string.

```
<f:format.raw><f:format.json value="{context: 'https://schema.org/'}" /></f:format.raw>
```

Or, probably nicer:

```
<f:variable name="jsonData" value="{context: 'https://schema.org/'}" />
{jsonData -> f:format.json() -> f:format.raw()}
```

That's equal to:

```
<f:variable name="jsonData" value="{context: 'https://schema.org/'}" />
<f:format.raw><f:format.json>{jsonData}</f:format.json></f:format.raw>
```

(In your case I think you have `jsonData` already as the variable `json`, don't you?)